# Shell command on Excel with long path name don't work

Tags: excel, vba, shell, batch-file, path

I have a batch file run.bat in a network folder "L:\Common Data\myfile" and i want to execute it from an Excel's macro.
Googling around I found these sintax:

```
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /k L:\Common Data\myfile\run.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

but it fails because it reads only "L:\Common".
I tryed many suggestion found on Internet but no one succeeded.
Someone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path names with spaces have to be wrapped in quotes.

```
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /k ""L:\Common Data\myfile\run.bat""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I discovered the problem in previous tests: the right number of double quote!